# Unityウィンドウの色の変更について

Tags: unity3d

Unityのデフォルト状態ではウィンドウの色は灰色になっています。

しかし、[この前unityのチュートリアル動画](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RFlh8pTf4DU)で、黒っぽい色に変更して

いるのをみました。プレイモード時の色を変更するのは、

Preferencesから設定することを知っていますが、

ウィンドウの色を変更するにはどうするのでしょうか？

回答よろしくお願いします。

Comment: そのチュートリアル動画のリンクが付いていないと思いますがー

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RFlh8pTf4DU
この動画です！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

残念ながら、Unityの`Preferences`の設定で少し色を変更することが出来るのに、ウインドウの色などを変更することにはUnityプロ・エディションが必要だと思います。私のUnityのバージョン(`4.3.2`)はちょっと古いのに、設定で、「ダーク・スキン」のそばで「Pro Only」という注意がやはりありますよね。

また、[このUnityのページ](https://unity3d.com/get-unity)をご覧になると、プロ・エディションには「Professional editor skin」同梱の状態ようですが。